# How to use visual controls in Indy? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, indy

My server must print some reports about its work. How can I use visual objects such as labels, edit boxes in the OneEecute event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same rule, for not modifying VCL objects in any thread except main thread, is valid here too. You should not change any of VCL controls in OnExecute event-handler, because that code will be run in the context of a worker thread spawn by Indy for every connection.

If you need to change graphical user interface, do it using Synchronize or Queue methods, or use a custom notification mechanism for notifying the main thread to do the GUI modification for you.

If you want to call Synchronize or Queue methods, you have to type-cast TIdYarn to TIdYarnOfThread which derives from TIdYarn and implements it with threads:

```
// Calling MyMethod using Synchornize inside TIdTcpServer.OnExecute event-handler   
TIdYarnOfThread(AContext.Yarn).Thread.Synchronize(MyMethod);


// Calling MyMethod using Queue inside TIdTcpServer.OnExecute event-handler  
TIdYarnOfThread(AContext.Yarn).Thread.Queue(MyMethod);
```

Comment: Tthread has static Synchronize() and Queue() methods in D7+, so you do not need to access the Yarn's internals directly.  Alternatively, use Indy's TIdSync and TIdNotify classes instead, which handle these details for you.

Comment: @Remy, thanks; specially for TIdSync and TIdNotify in Indy; I didn't know about them.

Comment: Your best using the TidNotify, as TidSynch can cause deadlocks if the main vcl thread waiting for the worker to terminate and the worker is waiting for the tidsynch method to finish in the main vcl thread.